# Primes in Congruence Classes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Let $\pi_1(x)$ denote the number of primes $p$ less than $x$ such that $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $\pi_3(x)$ the number of primes $p$ less than $x$ such that $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. How does one approach $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\pi_1(x)}{\pi_3(x)}$$ I remember seeing a theorem addressing this problem, but cannot remember its name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the combination of the Prime Number Theorem and Dirichlet's Theorem
on primes in arithmetic progressions. This states that
$$\pi_{a,n}(x)\sim\frac1{\phi(n)}\frac{x}{\ln x}$$
where $a$ is coprime to $n$ and $\pi_{a,n}(x)$ is the number of primes
$\equiv a\pmod n$ up to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit in your question is equal to 1, but it sounds like you're thinking of **Chebyshev's bias** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias)); see also [this section on the prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions).