# Number of primes $p$ less than $n$ s.t $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$

Tags: number-theory

I would like to find a lower and upper bound for the number of primes less than $n$ that are $3\pmod 4$. My guess is that it should be close to half of $\pi (n)$ but cannot find a proof or generate myself. Is there a way to prove some lower and upper bounds as we have for $\pi (n)$?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for the [modular prime counting function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularPrimeCountingFunction.html).  Specifically, you want an estimate for $\pi{4,3}(x)$.

Comment: [Related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307231/primes-in-congruence-classes). Also, see the [Polya conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pólya_conjecture).

Comment: [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) addresses this question.

Comment: Very useful links. Still I leave the question open for I could not find bounds yet. I will edit my question again after researching these articles. Thanks!

Comment: Use the fact that for some fixed $N$ and an $a$ such that $(N,a)=1$ we have $$\sum_{{p\leq x}\wedge{p\equiv a \mod N}}\frac{ \log p}p= \frac{\log x}{\varphi(N)}+O_N(1)$$ this is Dirichlet's theorem

Comment: @oren1 In the long term, the ratio between the number of primes of the form $4k+3$ and the number of primes tends to $\frac{1}{2}$, but concrete intervals often give more primes of the form $4k+3$ (See Chebycheff-bias)